# How can I run a script for 18 hours in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, time, multiprocessing

```
if __name__=='__main__':

print("================================================= \n")

print 'The test will be running for: 18 hours ...'
get_current_time = datetime.now()

test_ended_time = get_current_time + timedelta(hours=18)

print 'Current time is:', get_current_time.time(), 'Your test will be ended at:', test_ended_time.time()

autodb = autodb_connect()
db = bw_dj_connect()

started_date, full_path, ips = main()



pid = os.getpid()

print('Main Process is started and PID is: ' + str(pid))

start_time = time.time()

process_list = []

for ip in ips:
    p = Process(target=worker, args=(ip, started_date, full_path))
    p.start()
    p.join()
    child_pid = str(p.pid)
    print('PID is:' + child_pid)
    process_list.append(child_pid)

child = multiprocessing.active_children()
print process_list

while child != []:
    time.sleep(1)
    child = multiprocessing.active_children()


print ' All processes are completed successfully ...'
print '_____________________________________'
print(' All processes took {} second!'.format(time.time()-start_time))
```

I have got a python test script which should be running for 18 hours and then kill itself. The script uses multiprocessing for multi devices. The data I am getting from main() function will be changed by time.

I am passing these three args to worker method in multiprocessing.

How can I achieve that ?

Comment: Are you asking how to kill a process, or how to tell when 18 hours has passed?

Comment: You might find it easier to use the terminal command `timeout` to run your script.

Comment: The description prior to "How can I achieve that" makes it sound like you have already "achieved that".

Comment: You want to wait time? sleep: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/time_sleep.htm

Answer (score 0):

**if** you don't need to worry about cleanup too much on the child processes you can kill them using `.terminate()`

```
...
time.sleep(18 * 60 * 60) # go to sleep for 18 hours
children = multiprocessing.active_children()
for child in children:
    child.terminate()

for child in multiprocessing.active_children():
    child.join() # wait for the children to terminate
```

if you do need to do some cleanup in all the child processes then you need to modify their run loop (I'm assuming `while True`) to monitor the time passing and only have the second while loop above in the main program, waiting for the children to go away on their own.

Answer (score 0):

you are never comparing datetime.now() to test_ended_time.

```
# check if my current time is greater than the 18 hour check point.
While datetime.now() < test_ended_time and multiprocessing.active_children():
    print('still running my process.')

sys.exit(0)
```